# Elasic Existed Query Not working About Empty String

Tags: elasticsearch

According to Official 7.x document [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-exists-query.html#exists-query-top-level-params)

> While a field is deemed non-existent if the JSON value is null or [],
> these values will indicate the field does exist:
>
> Empty strings, such as "" or "-" Arrays containing null and another
> value, such as [null, "foo"] A custom null-value, defined in field
> mapping

However, My es not consider "" as not existed.
Here is my Data:

```
"_source" : {
      "chat_msg" : {
        "action" : "send",
        "from" : "t",
        "msgid" : "6505946507184390735_161_external",
        "msgtime" : 1623396135015,
        "msgtype" : "text",
        "roomid" : "",
```

Now, When I do Query As :

```
GET enterprise_chat_data/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "chat_msg.roomid"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

It Hit Nothing. Am I Wrong About Something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the documentation. In the documentation, it is written that **if a field have value as empty strings, such as "" or "-", then that field will be considered to be existing.**

Due to this when you are querying for `must_not` exists query for `"chat_msg.roomid"` field, you are getting empty results, as in the data you have indexed the value of `"chat_msg.roomid"` field as `""`

**Update 1:**

You can use term query to search for documents having field value of `chat_msg.roomid` as `""`

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "chat_msg.roomid.keyword": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: omy.... eye... My I Ask How to find all roomId which is ""?